# PHP Getting specific Integer from a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to extract the ID which is the first integer in the string below:

```
ID:40021223
CSQ(0-31): 31
Online
```

I only want the to get `40021223`

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What have you coded so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'ID:40021223';   //pass any string
echo $output = getID($str); 

function getID($str) {
   $res = explode(':',$str);  //split string with :
   if(in_array('ID',$res)) {  //if array contain Id then it will give the exact output else null
      return $res[1];
   } else {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
$str = "ID:40021223
CSQ(0-31): 31
Online";

$filteredNumbers = array_filter(preg_split("/\D+/", $str));
$firstOccurence = reset($filteredNumbers);
echo $firstOccurence;
```

**This code will output the first set of numbers from any string**

Here the output will be: **40021223**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$matches = [];
$x = "ID:40021223
CSQ(0-31): 31
Online";

preg_match("/(id:\K\d+)/i", $x, $matches);
$id = $matches[0]
```

This is saying " **(id:\d+)** find me the expression with **id:** followed by **any number of digits**, but we add the **\K** to reset the match start so u will be able to get the following part only.